# Why are these different ? $y^2=2x^2+C$ vs. $y=\sqrt{2x^2}+C$

Tags: calculus

If you have $$y^2=2x^2+C$$

why is this not equivalent to

$$y=\sqrt{2x^2}+C$$

Comment: I think second formula should be "$y=\sqrt{2x^2+C}$". Of course, It is still not equivalent to $y^2=2x^2+C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by square rooting you get : $\sqrt{2x^2 + C}$. Then constant C is "inside" the square root.

Comment: And even though C1 = C2, in general, and can be written as C, the key is that the C is inside the radical, and therefore, can not be written as a different constant outside.  It is still inside.

Answer (score 0):

When you square the second equation, you would get:

$$y^2=2x^2+2C\sqrt{2x^2}+C^2$$

The rest of the proof is left to the reader as an exercise.

---

Extra:

---

$$y^2=2x^2+C$$

$$2y\mathrm dy=2x\mathrm dx$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac xy=\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+C}}$$

---

$$y=\sqrt{2x^2}+C$$

$$y=x\sqrt{2}+C$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\sqrt2$$

---

They are only equal when $C=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

The first $C$ and the second $C$ are different.

Its $y=\sqrt{2x^2+C}$ and $\sqrt{a+b}\neq \sqrt a+\sqrt b$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=c+\sqrt{2x^2}\implies y-c=\sqrt2|x|$$

Squaring we get $$(y-c)^2=2x^2\iff2x^2=?$$

But by the first case $$2x^2=y^2-c$$